# GSON parsing of google places API

Tags: java, json, parsing, gson

I need a little help with creating classes which will be filled with GSON parser.
This is the output od autocomplete Google Places API:

```
{
   "predictions" : [
  {
     "reference" : "CjQtAA",
     "terms" : [
        {
           "offset" : 0,
           "value" : "Ladimirevci"
        },
        {
           "offset" : 13,
           "value" : "Hrvatska"
        }
     ],
     "types" : [ "locality", "political", "geocode" ]
  },
  {
     "reference" : "CjQtAAA",
     "terms" : [
        {
           "offset" : 0,
           "value" : "Ladimirevci"
        },
        {
           "offset" : 13,
           "value" : "Hrvatska"
        }
     ],
     "types" : [ "locality", "political", "geocode" ]
  }
],
  "status" : "OK"
}
```

**SOLUTION** thanks to MikO

Classes are:

```
public class GPlacesAPIResults {

    @SerializedName("predictions")
    public List<GPlacesAPILocation> predictions;

    @SerializedName("status")
    public String status;

}
```

Second:

```
public class GPlacesAPILocation implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4509808527882750586L;

    @SerializedName("reference")
    private String reference;

    @SerializedName("terms")
    private List<GPlacesAPIAddress> terms;

    @SerializedName("types")
    private List<String> types;

    }
```

Third:

```
public class GPlacesAPIAddress implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6916297127791361853L;

    @SerializedName("value")
    public String value;

    }
```

In app I call it like this

```
InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()); //results from places api

GPlacesAPIResults lcs = new Gson().fromJson( in , GPlacesAPIResults.class);
```

Thank you for the effort :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Result` class with an attribute `locations` doesn't make any sense... in fact I don't understand why you came up with that, since there's no `locations` element anywhere in your JSON!

Try something like this (following your *particular notation*):

```
Results
List<Locations> predictions;
String status;

Locations
String reference;
List <Addresses> terms;

Addresses
String value;
```

Comment: The issue is that there is only one predictions label and multiple reference/terms pairs. And will the gson crash if there aren't and pairs?

Comment: @Reeebuuk: `predictions` is a JSON array (surrounded by `[ ]`), so you have to parse it in a `List`... the number of elements in the array it's not important, there may be 1 object, 9999 or 0, in any case the `List<Locations> predictions` will be filled with those elements... Then, each one of those objects (you called it `Locations`), in turn, has exactly 1 `reference` element and 1 `terms` element... the latter is again an array... This model should be working!

Comment: You were right. I Had List<String> value in ma Address class. :-)